# Issues with using HashTable in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to use hashtable and when trying to search for an object,I do not see the object, but I can see it if I print it.

Node Class:

```
public class Node {

    int x;
    int y;


    public Node() {

        this.x=0;
        this.y=0;

    }

    public Node(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }



    public String toString(){

        return "(Node: x,y="+Integer.toString(x)+","+Integer.toString(y)+")";

    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class GridWalk {


    static Hashtable <Node, Integer> myMap;
    static Stack<Node> nodes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myMap = new Hashtable<Node,Integer>();
        nodes=new Stack<Node>();

        Node start=new Node(0,0);

        Node new1= new Node(100,100);
        myMap.put(new1,new Integer(1));
        Node new2=new Node (100,100);
        System.out.println("Already there ? huh: "+new2.toString()+" at "+myMap.get(new2)); 

    }
}
```

I am getting NULL when I do the print line. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override and implement the `equals` method in your Node class. The default implementation from `java.lang.Object` only compares equality of references, which is not suitable in your case.

```
Node new1 = new Node(100, 100);
Node new2 = new Node(100, 100);

System.out.println(new1.equals(new2)); // Your current code will print false
```

HashMap's rely on proper implementation of both `equals` and `hashCode` method in order to operate correctly. You should implement an `equals` method that reflects the objects logic. Something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) return true;

    final Node other = (Node) o;
    return ((getX() == o.getX()) && (getY() == o.getY());
}
```

You might also want to implement a `hashCode()` method on your `Node` object.

Comment: so, the method should be something like: Boolean equals(Node node1,Node node2), right ?

Comment: got it: public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
 return (this == obj);
}

Comment: No.  It needs to be in the `Node` class and have the exact signature `boolean equals(Object)`.

Comment: @CameronSkinner - yep, was editing in a longer answer. Didn't expect so many comments while I was doing so!

Comment: No `public boolean equals(Object o)`. You can convert `o` to a `Node` object and compare it against `this`. `this == obj` will not help you, since it is the default `Object.equals` implementation that is causing your trouble. Shamelessly advertise on [my blog post](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2011/05/java-vs-equals.html). You can translate the article using the right menu "Traduzir" combo box.

Comment: @Perception: It's not "you might also want to implement a `hashCode()` method"; it's "you **must** also implement a `hashCode()` method". If you override `equals` but not `hashCode` then they will be inconsistent and you will wind up with undefined behaviour from the `HashMap`.